# Passing a value back to the parent from a form

Tags: reactjs

I'm playing with passing values back to a parent with a very simple, but having trouble getting my head around how it is done.

The app i'm attempting is very simple. A functional child component has a drop down where the user can select a colour to update state on the main app.js, which changes the background colour of the div.

I'm hoping someone can help me by filling in the blanks. I know I need a function that will pass the value back to the parent. But having trouble connecting the dots.

I could do this by simply placing the form in app.js and using a ref, but the point of this exercise for myself is understanding how to values up to parents.

thanks for any help or solutions in advance from a react noob!

## BASE APP.JS COMPONENT

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './friedhead.svg';
import ColourSelect from './ColourSelect/ColourSelect';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

 state = {
 colour: 'Blue'
}

//I need some kind of function here, to pass through as props to update state with the users chosen value from the form!?

}

render() {

const colourSection = {
  padding: '30px',
  backgroundColor: this.state.colour,
  marginTop: '20px',
  paddingBottom: '150px'
};

return (

 <div className="App">

   <div style={colourSection}>
     <h3>Don't like this colour?</h3>

     <ColourSelect 
     changeColour={PASS A FUNCTION}
     colour={this.state.colour}/>

   </div>
 </div>

 );
}
}

export default App;
```

## COLOURSELECT FUNCTIONAL COMPONENT

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const ColourSelect = ( props ) => {

return (
  <div>

//Need to extract the value selected by the user somehow. I tried refs but no use in a functional component...

    <form
    className="form"
    onSubmit={NEED TO REFERENCE THE FUNC AS PROPS HERE?}>    
      <select
      className="textfield">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select a new colour</option>
          <option value="Blue">Blue</option>
          <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
          <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
          <option value="Yellow">Yellow</option>
      </select>

      <input
        className="mainbtn" 
        type="submit"
        value="Change"/>

    </form>
    <h1>{props.colour}</h1>
   </div>

 );
}

export default ColourSelect;
```

Upon colour selection and submit, the background colour inline styling in app.js will update to the users selection.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `this.changeColour` function as a props to child component like this:

`changeColour={this.changeColour}`.

You should now create that function in your parent component like this:

`const changeColour = (colour) => { // here add some logic like this.setState({ colour }) }`.

Then you can simply call that function in one of children component methods using props name that you given while passing it - in your example it would be `props.changeColour()` (notice parenthesis after changeColour which says that function is being called)`.

About destructuring:

I wrote "you should", so I deleted that from my answer and will answer here for your last question. You don't have to destructure props while declaring children component, but it is cleaner way for other programmers that you are working with. 
You could write:

```
const ColourSelect = ({ changeColour }) => { 
// and then call your function like this 
 const someFunction = () => {
   changeColour() // this is destructured name of function passed in parent component
 }
};
```

It is the way for telling take `changeColour` from props and add it to `changeColour` variable. You could also write in next line something like this:

`const { changeColour } = props;`

Comment: Thank you @viciousP ! One question, exactly what do you mean by 'destructure props' in the child component?

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer in terms of destructuring.